# Design reports using php like Crystal Reports in Asp.net

Tags: php, mysql

I've been using Crystal Reports to design reports in c# Asp.net.
What is the best alternative for that while using php and mysql.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/) to generate even very complex PDF reports.

If you are looking for a client-side reporting tool, then maybe try [Stimulsoft Reports.PHP](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-php) .